# can't add contacts keyboard is missing

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone 4.  I went to add a contact and my keyboard will not pop up.  Thus I cannot add or search contacts by name.  How can I fix this?

Comment: screenshot please

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the phone?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, reboot your phone and give a try once.

or

Try to add a contact from both dial pad and contacts. Hope one works among the two.

Comment: I had the same problem just now, restarting the phone fixed it, thank you!